# Expand the following sum.

Tags: calculus

Expand the following sum. $$\sum_{k=n}^{n+2} \frac{1}{k}$$.

I learn about summation Notation using online videos. However, I don't think I got this question right.

Here is what I did: $$\sum_{k=n}^{n+2} \frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}$$.

The above is my answer but I'm not confident. Please help me out.

Comment: What part are you unsure of? This follows from the definition of the summation notation.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got the answer right or not.

Comment: Your answer seems fine to me.

Comment: Really? Thank you so much! Would $$/frac{1}-{n}+frac{1}-{n+1}+frac{1}-{n+2}$$ be the final answer?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question we will begin by expanding the summation by doing the following:

$$\Large\sum_\limits{k=n}^{n+2}\frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}n+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1+1}$$
$$\begin{align}\Large\sum_\limits{k=n}^{n+2}\frac{1}{k}&=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)+n(n+2)+n(n+1)}{n(n+1)(n+2)}\\ &=\frac{n^2+3n+2+n^2+2n+n^2+n}{n^3+3n^2+2n} \\ &=\frac{3n^2+6n+2}{n^3+3n^2+2n}\end{align}$$
The final solution is boxed in red.
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{\Large\sum_\limits{k=n}^{n+2}\frac{1}{k}=\frac{3n^2+6n+2}{n^3+3n^2+2n}}$$